# Using adsl router as modem only?

Tags: networking, modem, dsl-modem

I have 2 network points(in two different location) that are RJ11 type and I need to use them and connect them to a switch(RJ45 of course) and make networking,

and the switch is near to one of the point. how can I utilize that RJ11 point ?

I know that If I have a modem then I need to have 2 of them and place them in both ends. but since the modem currently is an old tech and i cant find one in the market these day. So, is it posibble to use the ADSL router to act as modem only ?

if yes, then how to do it ?

and if no, what do you recommend in my case ?

Best Regards

Comment: People  don't really connect a switch to a modem, that's why switches have RJ45 and modems, well, they don't connect to switches! though err The "modem" might have one RJ45 port you could connect that to a switch though that's not really the modem part of it. You don't really get plain modems, though cable modems were quite plain, an RJ11 and an RJ45. You can use an ADSL Router(ADSL refers to the modem part), as a Modem-Switch, it may depend on the ADSL router in question. What you want is to put it in what is so-called called "bridge mode" which I think is bridge(switch) and modem.

Comment: I suggest you state what adsl modem you have and one can check whether it supports 'bridge mode' which you need.  It might be possible to do it even without bridge mode but bridge mode is the recommended way.

Comment: Dear @barlop,

So, If I bring the 2 routers and set them to the 'Bridge mode' and connect them through the RJ11 port and connect the 2 pc through the RJ45 port(in each router). at that time, will I get the same result as if i connect the 2 pc with RJ45 cable directly ? because this is the same case that I have, I need to convert analog to digital with existing RJ11.

Thanks alot

Comment: You'd set a router-modem combo(a device that is a router and modem) or router-switch-modem(a device that is a router switch and modem) to bridge mode. And You wouldn't use two modems. You use one modem and the RJ11 end of the modem takes a cable and plugs into the telephone socket. If you use more than one router-modem, then only one would be used as a modem. You could take a router-switch-modem device, set it to bridge mode which should turn off the router, and you can also then ignore the modem too, and just use it for the switch. You could have another in bridge mode and use the modem.

Comment: dear @barlop,

I think you didn't get me. I think it is a must to have 2 router'bridge mode' in both ends and from that router I get the rj45 connection and connect it to the switch or pc and the same is done for the other end. so, one end is connected to the pc and the other to the switch. because the distance is around 300 M. and how can I do that with only 1 router ! how is the other end is connected with rj45 ! I need both end rj45. correwct me if i'm wrong

thanks alot

Comment: so your name sounds are "Kuwaiti"?

Comment: You can use two router-modem-switches in bridge mode, but only use the modem in one of them.

Comment: @barlop

The thing that i know is that when i set the router to bridge mode, then it will act as a modem. and i need to place it in both location, so 2 their will be 2 modem. then how can i use 1 modem in that case !

if my point not clear yet, the only thing that i need is to use the existing rj11 cable and connect to my switch in one end and the other to pc.

how to do it ? this is all what i want :)

Comment: With wired devices, and that's what we're talking about, if you set a router-switch to bridge mode then it won't ONLY act as a modem, it will act as a switch too. A bridge is a switch. Your router-modem if it has many RJ45 ports it has a switch built into it. And even if it only has one RJ45 port I suppose it still has a switch in there to connect it internally to the controller behind the RJ11 port.

Comment: *"the modem currently is an old tech"* -- Are you referring to a dailup modem?  *"can I utilize that RJ11 point"* -- It's not proper to specify only the connector type.  Most of the older connectors can be used with several types of signals and protocols.  So mentioning just "RJ11" implies a telco connection, but could be POTS or a dialup modem or ADSL.  **If you have two ADSL modems, you cannot connect them together using their RJ11 ports.**  You can connect two dialup modem to each other (over a phone line of course).

Comment: @sawdust I agree. I'd add that, while I understand america apparently uses DSL, and then for the POTS - RJ11,  In the UK it's ADSL and the modem has an RJ11, then a cable to the wall goes to a uniquely british plug/socket for the POTS. http://www.ashdistribution.co.uk/images/products/large/130-2964.jpg That of course emphasises your point re "It's not proper to specify only the connector type".